# Cordova: Detect if input[type=file] supports click

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

Clicking on an input[type=file] works very good. Mostly. It doesn't work on Android 4.4.2 and 4.4.3, it doesn't allow to select camera on Android 6.0.1.

I've found [this camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera). The only bad thing about plugin - it doesn't allow user to select between camera and gallery or I can't find how to show such native dialog.

So I'm going to make a custom 'select image source' html dialog, but I'd like that custom dialog to be a graceful degradation rather than a solution. Clicking on an input provides better UX on supported devices.

Can I detect if calling click() on input[type=file] will show dialog like the one on a picture?

[image: native dialog sample]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: @jcesarmobile Edited question. I want dialog like one on the image for devices which support input click and plugin fallback for devices with no click support. Can I make it?

Comment: that dialog is only shown on iOS, so you can use cordova-plugin-device to detect iOS platform, and if it's not iOS then show your custom html dialog

Comment: @jcesarmobile some androids have same dialog, some do nothing when I click input and some do wrong thing. I want good dialog for good androids.